# fput csv not adding second line

Tags: php, csv

Can anybody see anything wrong with this code? $output is a multidimensional array, so I have flattened it, then split the Keys and Values into seperate arrays. I have done a var_dump of both $headers and $answers, but for some reason `fputscsv($buffer, $answers)` doesn't do anything. The headers appear fine, so something around that line is breaking :/

```
function buildcsv($output)
{
  $headers = array();
  $answers = array();

  foreach($output as $section) // Flatten sections into single array and remove config rows.
  {
     array_shift($section);
     array_pop($section);
     array_pop($section);

     foreach($section as $question => $answer)
     {
       array_push($headers, $question); // Build array for header row
       array_push($answers, $answer); // Build array for answers row
     }
  }

     array_push($headers, "Read terms and conditions"); // Add terms and consitions column.
     array_push($answers, "Yes");

     $buffer = fopen('php://temp', 'r+');
     fputcsv($buffer, $headers);
     fputcsv($buffer, $answers);
     rewind($buffer);
     $csv = fgets($buffer);
     fclose($buffer);
     return $csv;

 }
```

Comment: This seems overly complicated for a simple CSV creation...

Comment: `fputcsv($buffer, $answers);` is outside of the foreach loop, so you're only calling it once. As you're only putting one answers array, so it will only write one line of answers

Comment: @MarkBaker `$ouput` is an array of different sections from a form (Personal details, security questions etc.) So after pushing to the `$headers` and `$answers` array, there is just a row of headers (questions) and a row of answers. But the answers aren't being written, just the `$headers`

Comment: Also, I tried `var_dump($answers);` and the data is there, it just isn't being written to the csv

Comment: fputcsv() takes a single dimensional array; you look as though you're building a multi-dimensional array and expecting it still to work... one call to `fputcsv()` will write one line of a csv file

Comment: Ok, so the plot thickens. It turns out that `fopen(php://output)` returns all the data. Which suggessts it is some kind of server issue. The CSV is only a few bytes, so we shouldn't be hitting memory limits. And if it was a permission issue it should be blank, not just the first row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, based on the fact I only seem to have proper access to the output buffer for some reason, this is what I came up with. The function allows another block of code to convert the rsponse of a form to CSV format, which is then attached to an email.

```
// Generate csv
 function buildcsv($output)
 {
     $headers = array();
     $answers = array();

     foreach($output as $section) // Flatten sections into single array and remove config rows.
     {
        array_shift($section);
        array_pop($section);
        array_pop($section);
        foreach($section as $question => $answer)
        {
                array_push($headers, $question); // Build array for header row
                array_push($answers, $answer); // Build array for answers row
        }
     }

     array_push($headers, "Read terms and conditions"); // Add terms and conditions column.
     array_push($answers, "Yes");

     $buffer = fopen('php://output', 'r+');

     ob_start();

     fputcsv($buffer, $headers);
     fputcsv($buffer, $answers);

     rewind($buffer);
     $csv = ob_get_contents();

     ob_end_clean();
     return $csv;

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but it might be better to write this: "php://temp/file.csv" ?